# Get mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vsearch'@'localhost' (using password: YES) with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, escape
from vsearch import search4letters
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)


logf = r'E:\Python\head_first_python\Ch5_webapp\webapp\vsearch.log'


def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    """Log details of the web request and the results."""
    dbconfig = {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'user': 'vsearch',
        'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
        'database': 'vsearchlogDB',
    }

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    _SQL = """insert into log
              (phrase, lettters, ip, browser_string, results)
              values
              (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(
        _SQL, (req.form['pharse'],
               req.form['letters'],
               req.remote_addr,
               req.user_agent.browser,
               res, )
    )
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = str(search4letters(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html',
                           the_title=title,
                           the_phrase=phrase,
                           the_letters=letters,
                           the_results=results,)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to search4letters on the web!')


@app.route('/viewlog')
def view_the_log() -> 'html':
    contents = []
    with open(logf) as log:
        for line in log:
            contents.append([])
            for item in line.split('|'):
                contents[-1].append(escape(item))
    titles = ('Form Data', 'Remote_addr', 'User_agent', 'Results')
    return render_template('viewlog.html',
                           the_title='View Log',
                           the_row_titles=titles,
                           the_data=contents,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when it runs the log_request func, it says:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vsearch'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm sure the host, the username, the password and the database are right.

Python version: Python 3.8.0rc1

Platform: Windows 10

MySQL: MySQL(not MariaDB)

Can anyone help me?